# Increasing an edge weight. Shortest time to recompute an $MST$?

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree

I have an $MST$ tree $T$. I increase the weight of a single edge $e$ by $c$(a non negative constant).

I need to recompute an $MST$ as fast as i can. How I do this? The idea I had in mimd is to remove $e$ from $T$. Loop over all crossing edges between the two "halves" of $T$. See which one is minimal weight. Add her instead.

This will require $O(|E|)$ time. Is there a faster idea? Or does my idea requires less than $O(|E|)$?

I suspect a more efficient algorothm exists because i do not use the fact that $e$'s weight increased.

Answer (score 1):

If you're required to solve this "one-shot" problem, you're not allowed to perform any pre-processing, and you don't have any additional assumption, then a running time of $O(m)$ is the best you can hope for.

Indeed, consider an edge $e$ such that the fundamental cut $C_e$ induced by $e$ contains $\Theta(m)$ edges. All edges in $C_e$ have distinct weights that are strictly larger than the weight $w_e$ of $e$. For every value of $m$, it is easy to come up with a graph $G$ , an associated MST $T$, and and edge $e$ that satisfy these properties.

Suppose that there is a (deterministic) algorithm $A$ with a running time of $o(m)$. Then, when $A$ is run with inputs $G$, $T$, and $e$ there is at least one edge $f \in C_e$ whose weight is never read by $A$, and such that $f$ is not added to the new MST $T'$.

We can then run $A$ with inputs $G'$, $T$, and $e$, where $G'$ is a copy of $G$ in which the weight of edge $f$ has been set to $w_e$. The returned MST must still be $T'$, but this is incorrect since the new MST must include edge $f$.